# How to change speech tone in AS3 with Flex Air?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm using service of Google's text to speech on my flex project. Google uses Female voice. But I want to robotic voice. Is possible to change voice? (For example with pitch value.)

My functions (Perhaps be need.):

```
private var domain:String = "http://samed.us/";
private function speech(text:String):void
{
    text = escape(text);
    var url:String = domain+"speak_en_"+text;
    _sound = new Sound();
    _sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundPlay);
    _sound.load(new URLRequest(url));
}
private function soundPlay(event:Event):void
{
    var playIt:Sound = event.target as Sound;
    playIt.play();
}
```

Platform: Air for Android

Comment: this may help... http://iq12.com/blog/2009/08/25/real-time-pitch-shifting/

Comment: This is useful for me but its for Flash. I'm using flash builder (flex). Programs uses AS3  but I don't know transforms Flash to Flex. :(

Comment: @SamedDeger, it is basically the same. Try migrating the code, it is very simple. I doubt migration is even the right term :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the SoundTouch library in a project with good result:

https://github.com/also/soundtouch-as3